# Try to read data from binary file, failed to put it in struct

Tags: c, binaryfiles

Edited the code to be more simpler and without the linked list pointer.

Here is my struct

```
typedef struct megye
{ 
    int megye;
    int hektar1_min;
    int hektar1_max;
    int hektar1_tam;
    int hektar2_min;
    int hektar2_max;
    int hektar2_tam;
    int hektar3_min;
    int hektar3_tam;

}megye;
```

and I have tried without the "struct _megye *next;" line too.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fb;
    megye*p;

    p=(megye*)calloc(8,sizeof(megye));

    fb=fopen("tamogatas.dat", "rb");
    if (fb==NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open file");
    }
    while (fread(p, sizeof (megye), 7, fb))
    {
        printf("%d\n", p->megye);
    }
    fclose(fb);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a line from the text file which I converted to a binary file which I use here:

> 1 50 100 2 100 200 4 200 6

My goal is to put every number in a line to an int in the struct.

The program runs, puts random numbers in the struct (always changing, long numbers from 6 digits to about 13-14). The debugger says that he fread function reads the file's first line (fread's _base string) but it simply doesn't put it in the struct. What do I have to do to get my numbers into the struct?

Please be simple, I haven't slept in two days :(

Edit: I have to do it with a binary file because it's homework.

Comment: What kind of 'random' numbers are put into the struct? Are they always different, or always the same values? (And if so, what are they?)

Comment: It may be an issue related to memory alignement. Try to `printf(sizeof(megye))`. Does it correspond to 9 int ? Likely not : the structure has been padded so that each member is of size 8.

Comment: How did you "convert" the text file into a binary file? Binary files don't have "lines", so how are you able to "read the file's first line"?

Comment: I read one line into a string and wrote it into the binary file. I'm thinking that that was the problem and now I'm trying to do it char by char.

Comment: That's not a "binary file". Populate an actual copy of the structure with values, write that out as binary, and then use a hex editor to view that file. There's a clear difference. Also, why are you passing a hard-coded '7' to `fread`? If you have the content of one structure in an actual binary file, you'd want to read 1 of those structures from the file for each call to `fread`. If you're trying to allocate a buffer for all of the `megye` records in the file at once, you'd use the filesize / sizeof(megye) to determine the allocation size; you're passing `8` to `calloc` as well.

Comment: look at byte packing your structure with the proper compiler alignment options.

Comment: If the data in your binary file was generated with `fwrite(p, sizeof(megye), 7, fp)` where `p` is a pointer to an array of 7 `megye` structs, then this ought to work. But if it was generated any other way, then it is likely that the fields are not aligned properly in the binary file. If you also wrote the code to generate the binary file, make sure that reading and writing the file are done the same way. If you did not generate the binary file, you will have to examine it closely to understand how the bytes are aligned in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**example of one record read/write to binary file**

```
int main(){
    FILE *fb;
    megye orig = {1, 50, 100, 2, 100, 200, 4, 200, 6 };
    megye *p;

    fb=fopen("megye.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(&orig, sizeof(megye), 1, fb);//1 record of struct megye to binary file of megye.dat
    fclose(fb);

    p=(megye*)calloc(1, sizeof(megye));//memory ensure 1 record of struct megye

    fb=fopen("megye.dat", "rb");
    if (fb==NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't open file");
    }
    while (1==fread(p, sizeof(megye), 1, fb))//1 :read number of record
    {
        printf("%d %d ...\n", p->megye, p->hektar1_min);
    }
    fclose(fb);
    //_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```